# Python 2.7 - Find the number of web server hits

Tags: python

I am trying to compute the number of hits to a web server per 
calendar month (Dec, Jan, Feb, ..) by Year.

I am very new to Python so I don't even know where to begin.  I suppose you have to use some string split or regexp.

I am given a log file with the following output:

```
[31/Dec/1994:23:55:08 -0700] "GET 45.html HTTP/1.0" 200 5489  
remote - - [31/Dec/1994:23:56:55 -0700] "GET 2195.ps HTTP/1.0" 200 522318 
remote - - [31/Dec/1994:23:59:37 -0700] "GET 957.ps HTTP/1.0" 200 122146 
remote - - [01/Jan/1995:00:31:54 -0700] "GET index.html HTTP/1.0" 200 2797 
remote - - [01/Jan/1995:00:31:58 -0700] "GET 2.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2555
remote - - [01/Jan/1995:00:32:33 -0700] "GET 3.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 36403
remote - - [01/Jan/1995:01:39:21 -0700] "GET 20.html HTTP/1.0" 200 378
local - - [01/Jan/1995:01:47:41 -0700] "GET index.html HTTP/1.0" 200 2797
local - - [01/Jan/1995:01:47:49 -0700] "GET 39.html HTTP/1.0" 200 669
local - -
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I'm impressed you have a 20 year old log file :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting is more easy (IMO) than applying the regular expressions. You can extract these values with the following function by passing in a log line:

```
def year_month(s):
     try:
         discard, month, rest = s.split('/', 2)  # split twice on '/' 
     except ValueError:
         return None  # for last line without /
     year = rest.split(':', 1)[0]
     year = int(year)  # optional
     return year, month
```

You can use the returned tuple from this function as a key to some dictionary:

```
d = {}
for line in open('yourfile'):
    ym = year_month(line)
    if ym is None:
         continue
    x = d.setdefault(ym, [0])
    x[0] += 1
for ym in sorted(d):
    print('Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Hits: {2}'.format(ym[0], ym[1], d[ym][0]))
```

If you want to use regular expressions you can replace the `year_month()` part with:

```
import re

# see https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html
year_month_pattern = re.compile(r"""
.*/
(?P<month>.*)
/
(?P<year>\d*)
:.*
""", re.VERBOSE)

def year_month(s):
    res = year_month_pattern.match(s)
    if res is None:
        return None
    try:
        return int(res.group('year')), res.group('month')
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks . No changes to your code -  I get the following errors  -------                                                     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Hadoop-stat-class\apache1.py", line 18, in <module>
    print('Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Hits: {2}'.format(ym[0], ym[1], d[ym][0]))
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @user4745212 that was the 0 in the year_month function, should have been None. I edited that by hand instead of copying my (working) code in.

Comment: Sorry. new to python, Not sure what to change  to get rid of the TypeError.

Comment: I had already updated my answer the problem was in the `year_month()` function returning `0` instead of None (for lines that have no year/month info).

Comment: I have not tried regexp yet but thanks so much for your help. How long did it take you to master Python

Comment: @user4745212 I started using Python back in '98 (version 1.5.2) directly for a commercial solution. But I had experience with Basic, Pascal, Modula-2, C, C++, Prolog, Lisp,APL and some assembly languages before that. [Here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3169/33055) is part of that history. Python however is still my favourite by far.